# Better way of selecting two distinct objects

Tags: drools

In my code below, I am using the `id` property to distinguish between two objects (`$stp2` is not `$stp1`). How can I rather do it at **object-level**, instead of using some property?

```
rule "multipleSTPSamePeriod"
    when
        $stp1 : SubjectTeacherPeriod( $id:id, $period:period)
        $stp2 : SubjectTeacherPeriod(id>$id, period==$period)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the "this" special property:

```
rule "multipleSTPSamePeriod"
    when
        $stp1 : SubjectTeacherPeriod( $period:period )
        $stp2 : SubjectTeacherPeriod( this != $stp1, period==$period)
```

If you want that behavior on all your rules, though, you can set a knowledge base configuration option and the engine will automatically check that for you without the need to add the constraint to every pattern.

Using a system property or conf file you can set:

```
drools.removeIdentities = <true|false>
```

Or using the API:

```
KnowledgeBaseConfiguration conf = ...
conf.setOption( RemoveIdentitiesOption.YES );
```